# Mac Won't Remember Hostname in Terminal After Reboot, gives 'unknown...'

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to set my hostname for my mac.  Currently it's `unknown002374e31ebd`.

I've tried setting it with

```
sudo hostname -s Steve-Mac
```

Which will work for all future terminal sessions.  However, if I restart, it goes back to `unknown`

How can I get it to keep this setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the hostname via the Terminal is not permanent.

From the hostname manpage:

> DESCRIPTION
>   The hostname utility prints the name of the current host. The super-user can set the hostname by supplying an argument. To keep the hostname between reboots, run `scutil --set HostName name-of-host'.

Alternatively, set the hostname in your System Preferences, under the Sharing section.

Comment: Additionally, `-s` does not stand for "set". Also from the manpage: `-s    Trim off any domain information from the printed name.`

Comment: in my version of scutil, `-s` doesn't stand for anything, I get the following error when I try to run `scutil -s HostName Foobar`: `scutil: invalid option -- s`

Comment: I was talking about `hostname -s` not meaning what OP thought it meant. Indeed, `scutil` doesn't have a `-s` option.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way is to setup it in System Preferences -> Sharing (unlock screen by clicking padlock on bottom) and then change name and Apply.